# HTML Script cannot get fetch data

Tags: html, node.js, express, http, httprequest

I try to get my data from mongoDB then use res to send all content to client side but I keep getting undefined, can anyone help me? Thank yall!!!

```
//// server.js
app.get('/user/show', userController.userList);

//// controller
const usersList = async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find({});
    const usersStr = JSON.stringify(users);
    // tried console.log(userStr), can get correct output
    res.json({'users': usersStr});
}

//// HTML Script
async function test() {
    const result = fetch('/user/show',{ 
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Contect-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then((response) => response.json());;
    console.log(result.messages.);
}
test();
```

Comment: Ok I know why, I need await for async function

Answer (score 0):

If the data of the client come undefined myabe you dont have body-parser install.

> body-parser

```
npm i body-parser
```

> your index.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// app by app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
```

Comment: I did json and I have app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.text()); already